# Extbase Mapping with non-TYPO3-table

Tags: model-view-controller, typo3, extbase

I have too classes and two non-TYPO3-tables. I defined a non-TYPO3-table as a table without uid, pid, etc. columns.

**My two classes:**

1. class Tx_Abc_Domain_Model_Location extends Tx_Extbase_DomainObject_AbstractEntity
2. class Tx_Abc_Domain_Model_Facility extends Tx_Extbase_DomainObject_AbstractEntity

**My two tables (with columns):**

1. locations

   - zipcode
   - city
   - facility_id
2. facilities

   - facility_id
   - name

I've mapped the attributes like this:

```
config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes {
  Tx_Abc_Domain_Model_Location.mapping {
    tableName = locations
    columns {
        zipcode.mapOnProperty = zipcode
        city.mapOnProperty = city
        facility_id.mapOnProperty = facility
    }
  }
  Tx_Abc_Domain_Model_Facility.mapping {
    tableName = facilities
    columns {
        facility_id.mapOnProperty = uid
        name.mapOnProperty = name
    }
  }
}
```

**My problem:**

The facility attribute of my location model got the type `Tx_Abc_Domain_Model_Facility` and when I'm looking for a location via the LocationRepository it builds me a location model which contains a facility model.

The problem appears, when I the search I am doing returns several results. i.e. the location with the zipcode 12345 has two different facilities (and the table locations got two rows with different facility_ids), then I would expect to get two location models and each of it got the right facility model.

But instead I get the two location models, which have all same facility model inside. They've got all the facility of the first found location.

Even if I change the type of the facility attribute to integer, there are the wrong ids. But if I enable raw query result in repository I get the correct ids.

I get also the correct ids or models, when I add to both tables an uid-column.

**Is there no possibility to map tables without uid column with Extbase models?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, the answer to my last question is: Yes, there is no possibility to map tables without uid column with Extbase models.

There is an existing ticket on forge: http://forge.typo3.org/issues/25984

The reason seems to be the hardcoded `$row['uid']` in mapSingleRow() method in Tx_Extbase_Persistence_Mapper_DataMapper class.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not alot of tables you have to map, a work-around could be to create views for those tables to just map the uid.

I.e.:

```
CREATE VIEW tx_abc_domain_model_facility AS
    SELECT facility_id AS uid, facilities.* FROM facilities;
```